# UITableView scroll slow because of NSDictionary nested data?

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary, xib

I have a `NSDictionary` with lots of nested data. All this data is loaded once in my `UIViewController` and then my `UITableView` is reloaded, using this data to populate it's cell's labels, which are set in a separate `xib`. All the loading process happens pretty fast, but my `UITableView`'s scroll becomes very slow. I first thought it could be the `xib` being loaded each time a cell was allocated, so I tested the default `UITableViewCell` instead of loading it, but nothing changed.
Could this problem be caused by the way I access my data? I'm doing the following:

```
NSDictionary *match = dictionaryMatches[@"dates"][indexPath.section][@"matches"][indexPath.row];

homeTeamAbbreviationLabel.text = match[@"home"];
visitorTeamAbbreviationLabel.text = match[@"visitor"];
matchTimeLabel.text = match[@"time"];
leagueLabel.text = match[@"league"];

homeNameLabel.text = match[@"home_name"];
visitorNameLabel.text = match[@"visitor_name"];
```

And this code goes inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Any suggestions would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was. I had the cell identifier set in my `xib`, but was not using it in my code.

Before I fixed the problem it was:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell"]];
```

Now it is:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RegularMatchCell"]];
```

Now it works fine.